# Best way to serialize/unserialize objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, serialization

I have many JavaScript objects in my application, something like:

```
function Person(age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.isOld = function (){
        return this.age > 60;
    }
}
// before serialize, ok
var p1 = new Person(77);
alert("Is old: " + p1.isOld());

// after, got error Object #<Object> has no method 'isOld'
var serialize = JSON.stringify(p1);
var _p1 = JSON.parse(serialize);
alert("Is old: " + _p1.isOld());
```

See in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FQzm/1/).

My question is: is there a best practice/pattern/tip to recover my object in same type it was before serialization (instances of class Person, in this case)?

Requirements that I have:

- Optimize disk usage: I have a big tree of objects in memory. So, I don't want to store functions.
- Solution can use jQuery and another library to serialize/unserialize.

Comment: You need to provide some criteria by which "best" can be determined, e.g. fastest, most flexible, robust. The only way to serialise an object is to iterate over its properties and create a text representation of the property and its value. Whether you use some built-in function (e.g. *JSON.stringify*) or write your own depends on whether you have specific requirements that can't be met by *JSON.stringify*.

Comment: @RobG: I've updated my question. Best to me is low disk usage and flexive (I can have many types of objects in my tree)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

JSON has no functions as data types. You can only serialize strings, numbers, objects, arrays, and booleans (and `null`)

You could create your own `toJson` method, only passing the data that really has to be serialized:

```
Person.prototype.toJson = function() {
    return JSON.stringify({age: this.age});
};
```

Similar for deserializing:

```
Person.fromJson = function(json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(json); // Parsing the json string.
    return new Person(data.age);
};
```

The usage would be:

```
var serialize = p1.toJson();
var _p1 = Person.fromJson(serialize);
alert("Is old: " + _p1.isOld());
```

---

To reduce the amount of work, you could consider to store all the data that needs to be serialized in a special "data" property for each `Person` instance. For example:

```
function Person(age) {
    this.data = {
        age: age
    };
    this.isOld = function (){
        return this.data.age > 60 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

then serializing and deserializing is merely calling `JSON.stringify(this.data)` and setting the data of an instance would be `instance.data = JSON.parse(json)`.

This would keep the `toJson` and `fromJson` methods simple but you'd have to adjust your other functions.

---

Side note:

You should add the `isOld` method to the prototype of the function:

```
Person.prototype.isOld = function() {}
```

Otherwise, every instance has it's own instance of that function which also increases memory.

Comment: But you can convert a JavaScript function to a string, and then store that string in the JSON.  Then when you parse the JSON you can convert the string back to a function and execute it.

Comment: @aroth: But why would you want to do that? It (a) increases the amount of storage needed (b) is redundant. If you store 100 persons, why would you want to store the same string representation of a function 100 times? Only data should be serialized. In this case, the function is not data.

Comment: @aroth: I'm thinking same thing than felix. I DON'T want to store functions. I have a very big tree of objects, I need to optimize disk/processor usage. By the way, thanks!

Comment: @Topera: You're welcome. I cannot say whether this is the "best" way, but I hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: @Felix - I don't know why you'd want to, my point wasn't that it should be done, just that it is technically possible to serialize and deserialize functions in JSON.  Here's a working demo, if anyone is curious:  http://jsfiddle.net/8FQzm/4/

Comment: @Pointy: The poor booleans! How I could I forget them?! :)

Comment: May I ask why you use `return this.data.age > 60 ? true : false;` instead of just `return this.data.age > 60;`

Comment: @whirlwin: Well, this answer is over a year old, so I cannot tell you for sure, but I assume it's just copy and paste from the question. But you are absolutely right, this is unnecessary.

Comment: Shouldn't it be toJSON and fromJSON (capitalized) ?

Comment: @quick: If you want to use toJSON in the context of JSON.stringify, then yes. If it just bothers you because JSON is usually capitalized, I agree ;) I wrote the answer two years ago and probably didn't care this that much back then. Aside from that it doesn't matter what the method names are.

Comment: Ah yeah, I get what you did here. This answer may confuse some newbies though. So newbies: make sure you grok JSON prior.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Person.prototype.fromJson` instead of `Person.fromJson`?

Comment: No @OlivierPons. At least in this example fromJSON is supposed to be a static method.

Comment: Note this only works in simple cases when there are no circular object references. E.g. when persons reference their child persons and parent persons, then `JSON.stringify` would throw a `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Answer (score 8):

I wrote **serialijse** because I faced the same problem as you.

you can find it at https://github.com/erossignon/serialijse

It can be used in nodejs or in a browser and can serve to serialize and deserialize a complex set of objects from one context (nodejs) to the other (browser) or vice-versa.

```
var s = require("serialijse");


var assert = require("assert");


// testing serialization of a simple javascript object with date
function testing_javascript_serialization_object_with_date() {

    var o = {
        date: new Date(),
        name: "foo"
    };
    console.log(o.name, o.date.toISOString());

    // JSON will fail as JSON doesn't preserve dates
    try {
        var jstr = JSON.stringify(o);
        var jo = JSON.parse(jstr);
        console.log(jo.name, jo.date.toISOString());
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(" JSON has failed to preserve Date during stringify/parse ");
        console.log("  and has generated the following error message", err.message);
    }
    console.log("");



    var str = s.serialize(o);
    var so = s.deserialize(str);
    console.log(" However Serialijse knows how to preserve date during serialization/deserialization :");
    console.log(so.name, so.date.toISOString());
    console.log("");
}
testing_javascript_serialization_object_with_date();


// serializing a instance of a class
function testing_javascript_serialization_instance_of_a_class() {

    function Person() {
        this.firstName = "Joe";
        this.lastName = "Doe";
        this.age = 42;
    }

    Person.prototype.fullName = function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };


    // testing serialization using  JSON.stringify/JSON.parse
    var o = new Person();
    console.log(o.fullName(), " age=", o.age);

    try {
        var jstr = JSON.stringify(o);
        var jo = JSON.parse(jstr);
        console.log(jo.fullName(), " age=", jo.age);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(" JSON has failed to preserve the object class ");
        console.log("  and has generated the following error message", err.message);
    }
    console.log("");

    // now testing serialization using serialijse  serialize/deserialize
    s.declarePersistable(Person);
    var str = s.serialize(o);
    var so = s.deserialize(str);

    console.log(" However Serialijse knows how to preserve object classes serialization/deserialization :");
    console.log(so.fullName(), " age=", so.age);
}
testing_javascript_serialization_instance_of_a_class();


// serializing an object with cyclic dependencies
function testing_javascript_serialization_objects_with_cyclic_dependencies() {

    var Mary = { name: "Mary", friends: [] };
    var Bob = { name: "Bob", friends: [] };

    Mary.friends.push(Bob);
    Bob.friends.push(Mary);

    var group = [ Mary, Bob];
    console.log(group);

    // testing serialization using  JSON.stringify/JSON.parse
    try {
        var jstr = JSON.stringify(group);
        var jo = JSON.parse(jstr);
        console.log(jo);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(" JSON has failed to manage object with cyclic deps");
        console.log("  and has generated the following error message", err.message);
    }

    // now testing serialization using serialijse  serialize/deserialize
    var str = s.serialize(group);
    var so = s.deserialize(str);
    console.log(" However Serialijse knows to manage object with cyclic deps !");
    console.log(so);
    assert(so[0].friends[0] == so[1]); // Mary's friend is Bob
}
testing_javascript_serialization_objects_with_cyclic_dependencies();
```

Comment: thanks for the library, how do you use it on the browser without the require?

Comment: You can now use bower to install ```serialijse```. ```bower install  serialijse```

Comment: It seems some clasess can't be deserialized. "class PreEnactedPolicy is not registered in class Factory - deserialization will not be possible"

Comment: No luck:  ' class PreEnactedPolicy is not registered in class Factory - deserialization will not be possible'

Answer (score 5):

I am the author of https://github.com/joonhocho/seri.

Seri is JSON + custom (nested) class support.

You simply need to provide `toJSON` and `fromJSON` to serialize and deserialize any class instances.

Here's an example with nested class objects:

```
import seri from 'seri';

class Item {
  static fromJSON = (name) => new Item(name)

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  toJSON() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

class Bag {
  static fromJSON = (itemsJson) => new Bag(seri.parse(itemsJson))

  constructor(items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  toJSON() {
    return seri.stringify(this.items);
  }
}

// register classes
seri.addClass(Item);
seri.addClass(Bag);


const bag = new Bag([
  new Item('apple'),
  new Item('orange'),
]);


const bagClone = seri.parse(seri.stringify(bag));


// validate
bagClone instanceof Bag;

bagClone.items[0] instanceof Item;
bagClone.items[0].name === 'apple';

bagClone.items[1] instanceof Item;
bagClone.items[1].name === 'orange';
```

Hope it helps address your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The browser's native JSON API may not give you back your idOld function after you call JSON.stringify, *however*, if can stringify your JSON yourself (maybe use [Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) instead of browser's API), then if you have a string of JSON e.g.

```
var person_json = "{ \"age:\" : 20, \"isOld:\": false, isOld: function() { return this.age > 60; } }";
```

then you can call

```
eval("(" + person + ")")
```

, and you will get back your function in the json object.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, and written a small tool to do the mixing of data and model. See https://github.com/khayll/jsmix

This is how you would do it:

```
//model object (or whatever you'd like the implementation to be)
var Person = function() {}
Person.prototype.isOld = function() {
    return this.age > RETIREMENT_AGE;
}

//then you could say:
var result = JSMix(jsonData).withObject(Person.prototype, "persons").build();

//and use
console.log(result.persons[3].isOld());
```

It can handle complex objects, like nested collections recursively as well.

As for serializing JS functions, I wouldn't do such thing because of security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I've added yet another JavaScript serializer repo to GitHub.

Rather than take the approach of serializing and deserializing JavaScript objects to an internal format the approach here is to serialize JavaScript objects out to native JavaScript. This has the advantage that the format is totally agnostic from the serializer, and the object can be recreated simply by calling eval().

https://github.com/iconico/JavaScript-Serializer

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and since I couldn't find a sufficient solution, I also created a serialization library for javascript: https://github.com/wavesoft/jbb (as a matter of fact it's a bit more, since it's mainly intended for bundling resources)

It is close to Binary-JSON but it adds a couple of additional features, such as metadata for the objects being encoded and some extra optimizations like data de-duplication, cross-referencing to other bundles and structure-level compression.

However there is a catch: In order to keep the bundle size small there are no type information in the bundle. Such information are provided in a separate "profile" that describes your objects for encoding and decoding. For optimization reasons this information is given in a form of script.

But you can make your life easier using the `gulp-jbb-profile` (https://github.com/wavesoft/gulp-jbb-profile) utility for generating the encodeing/decoding scripts from simple YAML object specifications like this:

```
# The 'Person' object has the 'age' and 'isOld'
# properties
Person:
  properties:
    - age
    - isOld
```

For example you can have a look on the `jbb-profile-three` profile.
When you have your profile ready, you can use JBB like this:

```
var JBBEncoder = require('jbb/encode');
var MyEncodeProfile = require('profile/profile-encode');

// Create a new bundle
var bundle = new JBBEncoder( 'path/to/bundle.jbb' );

// Add one or more profile(s) in order for JBB
// to understand your custom objects
bundle.addProfile(MyEncodeProfile);

// Encode your object(s) - They can be any valid
// javascript object, or objects described in
// the profiles you added previously.

var p1 = new Person(77);
bundle.encode( p1, 'person' );

var people = [
        new Person(45),
        new Person(77),
        ...
    ];
bundle.encode( people, 'people' );

// Close the bundle when you are done
bundle.close();
```

And you can read it back like this:

```
var JBBDecoder = require('jbb/decode');
var MyDecodeProfile = require('profile/profile-decode');

// Instantiate a new binary decoder
var binaryLoader = new JBBDecoder( 'path/to/bundle' );

// Add your decoding profile
binaryLoader.addProfile( MyDecodeProfile );

// Add one or more bundles to load
binaryLoader.add( 'bundle.jbb' );

// Load and callback when ready
binaryLoader.load(function( error, database ) {

    // Your objects are in the database
    // and ready to use!
    var people = database['people'];

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made an npm module named [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer) to solve this problem: save JavaScript class object values during serialization, in plain JSON format, without storing any functions. During the serialization, the only overhead incurred is saving the class names information. Thus, the disk usage is optimized.

Later on during the deserialization stage, esserializer can recursively deserialize object instance, with all types/functions information retained. It works in both browser and Node.js environment.

In the OP's case, the code would be pretty easy:

```
var ESSerializer = require('esserializer');

function Person(age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.isOld = function (){
        return this.age > 60;
    }
}
// before serialize, ok
var p1 = new Person(77);
alert("Is old: " + p1.isOld());

// serialize
var serializedText = ESSerializer.serialize(p1);
//...do something, or send the above serializedText to another JavaScript environment.
// deserialize
var deserializedObj = ESSerializer.deserialize(serializedText, [Person]);
alert("Is old: " + deserializedObj.isOld());
```

the `deserializedObj` is a `Person` instance, which contains all values/functions/superclasses information.

Wish it could help.

Comment:  Just wanted to give my recommendation to `esserializer`. I had an ArrayBuffer and a uInt8Array and have the same concerns - no eval, something that works in the browser and the server, actively maintained, etc. I was able to immediately serialize and deserialize back to the same values and delete a bunch of my own custom (buggy) code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty instance of of your class and assign values to it with `Object.assign`.

```
let p1 = new Person(77);
let serialized = JSON.stringify(p1);
let deserialized = Object.assign(new Person(), JSON.parse(serialized))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this with `Date` with native `JSON`...

```
function stringify (obj: any) {
  return JSON.stringify(
    obj,
    function (k, v) {
      if (this[k] instanceof Date) {
        return ['$date', +this[k]]
      }
      return v
    }
  )
}

function clone<T> (obj: T): T {
  return JSON.parse(
    stringify(obj),
    (_, v) => (Array.isArray(v) && v[0] === '$date') ? new Date(v[1]) : v
  )
}
```

What does this say? It says

- There needs to be a unique identifier, better than `$date`, if you want it more secure.

```
class Klass {
  static fromRepr (repr: string): Klass {
    return new Klass(...)
  }

  static guid = '__Klass__'

  __repr__ (): string {
    return '...'
  }
}
```

This is a serializable Klass, with

```
function serialize (obj: any) {
  return JSON.stringify(
    obj,
    function (k, v) { return this[k] instanceof Klass ? [Klass.guid, this[k].__repr__()] : v }
  )
}

function deserialize (repr: string) {
  return JSON.parse(
    repr,
    (_, v) => (Array.isArray(v) && v[0] === Klass.guid) ? Klass.fromRepr(v[1]) : v
  )
}
```

I tried to do it with Mongo-style Object (`{ $date }`) as well, but it failed in `JSON.parse`. Supplying `k` doesn't matter anymore...

BTW, if you don't care about libraries, you can use `yaml.dump` / `yaml.load` from `js-yaml`. Just make sure you do it the dangerous way.

Answer (score 0):

[json-stash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stash) can serialize anything you can define a serializer for.

```js
import { stash, unstash, addSerializers } from 'json-stash'

function Person(age) {
  this.age = age;
  this.isOld = function () {
    return this.age > 60;
  };
}
var p1 = new Person(77);
expect(p1.isOld()).toBe(true);

// add a serializer
addSerializers({ type: Person, save: (p) => [p.age] });

// serialize to JSON
var serialize = stash(p1);
expect(serialize).toBe('{"$type":"Person","data":[77]}');

// deserialize to Person object
var _p1 = unstash(serialize);
expect(_p1).toBeInstanceOf(Person);
expect(_p1.isOld()).toBe(true);
```