# Rebuilding an object serialized in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

In my web app, I'm serializing objects for storage using [JSON.stringify() as described here](http://www.json.org/js.html). This is great, and I can easily re-create the objects from the JSON strings, but I lose all of the objects' methods. Is there a simple way to add these methods back to the objects that I'm overlooking - perhaps involving prototyping, something I'm not overly familiar with?

Or is it just a case of creating an elaborate function of my own for doing this?

Edit: Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
Object.inheritMethods(AnotherObject);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to serialize/unserialize objects in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487699/best-way-to-serialize-unserialize-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: I suppose the solution there could work for me, with some modifications. I guess I was hoping for something more like Object.inheritMethods(Object2) though - I'll clarify the original post to specify this.

Comment: In browsers which support it, you might be able to use `Object.create`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: That looks promising, I'll have a play with it now.

Comment: That worked perfectly, once I fixed the rest of my bugs :) If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your object after calling JSON.parse, you have many options.  Here's a few examples.

1. Mixin

   There are many techniques for doing this, which [this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) article describes nicely.  However, here's a simple example that doesn't require any new language features.  Remember that an object is essentially just a map, so JS makes it easy to add additional properties to an object.

   ```
   var stuffToAdd = function() {
       this.name = "Me";        

       this.func1 = function() {
           print(this.name);
       }

       this.func2 = function() {
           print("Hello again");
       }
   }

   var obj = JSON.parse("{}");
   stuffToAdd.call(obj);
   ```
2. Prototypical

   Use the [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method that Felix mentioned.  Since this is only offered in ES5, you may want to use a [shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/) to guarantee its availability.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I found it when searching for that problem today.
I've found a solution elsewhere and uptodate (ES6):

Object.assign(new myclass(), jsonString);

Comment: It should be noted this will only work for classes which have no constructor parameters or constructors with no side effects.