# How to serialise a javascript object

Tags: javascript, serialization, javascriptserializer

When you serialise a form using jQuery.serialize(), the method will serialise the form fields and its values so you can submit to the server. Is there a method/function that would do the same with a javascript object instead of a form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487699/best-way-to-serialize-unserialize-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`jQuery.param` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Comment: It is jQuery.param() used with decodeURIComponent so the end code would be: `var myvar = decodeURIComponent($.param(myObj))`

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK: That depends on how you send it to the server, of course :-)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
JSON.stringify({x: 5, y: 6}); // '{"x":5,"y":6}' or '{"y":6,"x":5}'
```