# Serialize and deserialize JS object

Tags: javascript, string, serialization, deserialization

I lately was experimenting with the object serialization in JavaScript. I have already been looking through some of the questions concerning the serialization and deserialization of predefined object in Javascript, but I am looking for a more general solution. An example of this would be:

```
function anObject(){
    var x = 1;
    this.test = function(){return x;};
    this.add = function(a){x+a;};
}
var x = new anObject();
x.add(2);
console.log(x.test());
>>> 3
var y = deserialize(serialize(x));
console.log(y.test());
>>> 3
```

Is there a way to serialize this object and deserialize it, such that the deserialized object still have access to the local variable x without the use of the prototype of that object (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487699/best-way-to-serialize-unserialize-objects-in-javascript) solution)?

I have already tried by just storing the function as a string and evaluating it again, but then the state of an object can not be saved.

Comment: You can't access the execution context/environment of a closure, so I really don't think it's possible what you are trying to do.

Comment: you can use the revive param on JSON.parse() to turn stringified methods into real functions using eval or Function. you also need to define Function.prototype.toJSON to produce a smoking-gun signature that your reviver function can detect. with those two pieces and given no method needs outside variable closure and you publish used properties, you can accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible without code introspection and code re-writing which I think is not a good idea. However, what about something like this?

```
function AnObject() {
    var x = 1;

    this.x = function () { return x; };
    this.addToX = function (num) { x += num; };
    this.memento = function () {
        return { x: x };
    };
    this.restoreState = function (memento) {
        x = memento.x;
    };
}


var o = new AnObject();

o.addToX(2);
o.x(); //3

var serializedState = JSON.stringify(o.memento()),
    o = new AnObject();

o.restoreState(JSON.parse(serializedState));

o.x(); //3
```

However, **please note that having priviledged members comes at a great cost** because you lose the benefits of using prototypes. For that reason I prefer not enforcing true privacy and rely on naming conventions such as `this._myPrivateVariable` instead (unless you are hiding members of a module).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. While the answer from [plalx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211528/plalx) works perfectly for specific objects, I wanted to have something more general which just works for any object you throw at it.

Another solution one can use is something like this:

```
function construct(constructor, args, vars) {
    function Obj() {
        var variables = vars
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
    Obj.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new Obj();
}

function addFunction(anObject, aFunction, variables) {
    var objectSource = anObject.toString();
    var functionSource = aFunction.toString();
    objectSource = objectSource.substring(0,objectSource.length-1);
    var functionName = functionSource.substring(9, functionSource.indexOf('('));
    var functionArgs = functionSource.substring(functionSource.indexOf('('), functionSource.indexOf('{')+1);
    var functionBody = functionSource.substring(functionSource.indexOf('{')+1, functionSource.length);
    return objectSource + "this." + functionName + " = function" + 
           functionArgs + "var variables = " + variables + ";\n" + functionBody + "}";
}

function makeSerializable(anObject) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(anObject, function(key, val) {
            return ((typeof val === "function") ? val+'' : val);
        });
    var variables = [];
    while(obj.indexOf("var") > -1) {
        var subString = obj.substring(obj.indexOf("var")+3, obj.length-1);
        while (subString[0] == " ")
            subString = subString.replace(" ", "");
        var varEnd = Math.min(subString.indexOf(" "), subString.indexOf(";"));
        var varName = subString.substring(0, varEnd);
        variables.push(varName);

        obj = obj.replace("var","");
    }

    var anObjectSource = addFunction(anObject, 
        function serialize(){
            var vars = [];
        console.log("hidden variables:" + variables);
        variables.forEach(function(variable) {
            console.log(variable + ": " + eval(variable));
            vars += JSON.stringify([variable, eval(variable)]);
        });

        var serialized = [];
        serialized.push(vars);
        for (var func in this){
            if (func != "serialize")
                serialized.push([func, this[func].toString()]);
        }
        return JSON.stringify(serialized);
        },
        JSON.stringify(variables));
    anObject = Function("return " + anObjectSource)();

    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    params.shift();

    return construct(anObject, params, variables);
}
```

This allows you to serialize all elements of any object, including the hidden variables. The serialize() function can then be replaced by a custom string representation for the hidden variables, which can be used when deserializing the string representation to the object.

usage:

```
function anObject(){
   var x = 1;
   var y = [1,2];
   var z = {"name": "test"};
   this.test = function(){return x;};
   this.add = function(a){x+a;};
}

var test = makeSerializable(anObject)

test.serialize()
>>>["[\"x\",1][\"y\",[1,2]][\"z\",{\"name\":\"test\"}]",["test","function (){return x;}"],["add","function (a){x+a;}"]]
```

Comment: It works, but it's kinda hacky and btw, to get the source of a function there's no need to use `JSON.stringify`, you can just do `anObject.toString()`. Since you are modifying the constructor it's also breaking a few things such as `o instanceof anObject` returning false. You should rather avoid enforcing true privacy which will allow you to use prototypes and avoid having to do code introspection and rewriting to serialize your objects.