# jQuery: Filtering by data doesn't work

Tags: jquery, filter

I've done a lot of images for a small game.
In each image, I store an integer through a function using this advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6487719/106140)

Like this:

```
for (var idx=0; idx<jeu.length; idx++) {
    $('#jeu').append(
        $('<img />').data('idx', idx)
    );
}
```

Then I check I can retrieve it "by hand":

```
> $('img')[11]
<img src="imgs/bleu.gif" />
> $($('img')[11]).data()
Object {idx: 5}
```

Now if i try to retrieve  the object through `data` filter it doesn't work:

```
> $('img[data-idx="Object {idx: 5}"]')
[]
> $('img[data-idx="idx: 5"]')
[]
```

What is the way to do it?

Comment: use this $('img[data-idx="5"]') ?

Comment: can you show how  data-idx assigned to img . you can see it in console

Comment: In the data() there's  an object: `$($('img')[11]).data()` gives `Object {idx: 5}` but if I do `$($('img')[11])` i see there's not property like `data-idx` so I dont know howw to retrieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the data api to set the value, which does not update the element attributes, in this case you can use .filter()

```
$('img').filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('idx') == 5
})
```

---

Another choice is to use attribute

```
('<img />').attr('data-idx', idx)
```

then

```
$('img[data-idx="5"]')
```

Comment: wow. i'll try, this may  work but this is the fastest way to store values and retrieve them fast, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$("body").data("idx", 5);

var filterdata = function(key, val) {
  return $.map($("*"), function(el, i) {
    return $.data(el, key) === val ? $.data(el) : null
  })[0]
};

console.dir(filterdata("idx", 5));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div></div>
```