# Meteor JS: Sharing Objects From Server with Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In my Meteor web app, the client makes a Meteor.call to a server method.
The server method makes some calculations and returns a instantiated object of this function:

```
function Chart(name){
  var o = new Object();
  o.name = name;
  o.bhavas = [];
  o.getSign = function(sign){
    //console.log('end of getSign');
  };
  o.getHouse = function(num){
    //
  }
  return o;
}//end of Chart
```

Back in the client, when I examine the object passed, I find a object only with '`name`' and '`bhavas`'

e.g.: Object { name="D1",  bhavas=[12]}

It has lost the other properties such as getSign and getHouse.

The above declaration of the `function Chart...`
is only in the server file and not in the client file.

My question is, is it possible to share objects from server and client without losing any of the properties when passed between them????

How???

or am I left with the solution of using `_.extend()` to reattach the properties on the client side??

I was hoping for a smarter solution if one does exist.
Thank you very much....

Comment: Use Meteor methods instead. There shouldn't be a need to have every instance of an object have its own handler functions.

Comment: I guess, the data between the client and server is transferred in JSON format and functions are not valid value type. So when you create an object from 'Chart' and try to send it to the client, the object is serialized to JSON, 'name' and 'bhavas' are both in valid value types (string and array), so they will be included, but 'getSign' and 'getHouse' are functions hence they are lost

Comment: Hi, I am using Meteor methods.  Within the meteor method it does var x = new Chart('D1'); return x....and so x gets transferred to client but in the client side x loses the getSign and getHouse properties....

Comment: So, no choice but to reattach it on the client side?  No other smarter way of solving this?

Comment: One way I personally would recommend you is to have 'Chart' declaring all data values (strings, numbers, booleans, arrays etc.) as its own properties and all functions as prototypes of Chart. This way when you get the JSON content to the client, you can deserialize it to 'Chart' object and you will have access to its prototypes (these functions).

Comment: Hi...ok I tried this...  function PassMe(){
          this.name ='PassMe';
        }
        PassMe.prototype.whatever = 'Whatever';
        PassMe.prototype.doSomething = function(x){

          console.log('do something');

        } 


        var passme = new PassMe();
 and returning passme ....but I'm only getting this  Object { name="PassMe"} ...how do you deserialise it to show the doSomething function?  Thank you...

Comment: Ok...I think u meant to do it like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487699/best-way-to-serialize-unserialize-objects-in-javascript

Comment: I did JSON.stringify(passme) but it still was just Object { name="PassMe"}

Comment: Method return values must be [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson), which only allows a limited number of property prototypes in addition to literals.  To add more, have a look at [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson_add_type), but you'll still have to add function properties (i.e. methods) again on the client side.

Comment: @preston yeah, pretty much this is what you can do. Look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mkazqmem/2/)