# Object serialize like form data serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure if I am missing something or that is doesnt work like I think it does. I have some form data that I want to split. To do this I thought I could create another object with the values i want to like this:

```
let data = $('form').serializeArray();
let answers = {};
data.forEach(function(element) {
    // check if the element contains a answer input value
    if(element.name.indexOf('answer') !== -1) {
        answers[element.name] = element.value;
    }
});

console.log($('form').serialize()); 
// output:  answer%5B1%5D=1&answer%5B2%5D=2&answer%5B4%5D=3&answer%5B3%5D=4&sort=relevance&query=&area=..... etc
console.log(answers.serialize());   
// output: is not a function.
```

So again. I thought you could serialize a object to a string for data storage like I do with the form data.

Can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong and/or why serialize does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to serialize/unserialize objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487699/best-way-to-serialize-unserialize-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @PatrickEvans That wil just convert it to a json string but not like a url params string like the serialize does. But someone answer my question, ty tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`answers` is not a jQuery object so it doesn't have a `serialize()` method. If you wanted to get a name-value pair string like you get with jQuery's serialize then you can use [jQuery's param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) method

```js
answers = {
  "answer1":1,
  "answer2":2
};
console.log(jQuery.param(answers));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise if you are just wanting to serialize `answers` to JSON so that you can later recreate it then you just use `JSON.stringify`

```js
    answers = {
      "answer1":1,
      "answer2":2
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(answers));
```